# Dynamic Config File with Generics and dynamic keyword in C#

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic

My goal is to create a Configuration class that can store and persist strongly-typed values. The approach I've taken is below. My whole design may be flawed, but this is my third time rewriting from scratch, and I'm not sure how else to approach this problem. I am encountering trouble when trying to implement a dynamic method to get a value.

Specifically, I am wondering how to store a Type and use it later as a Type Parameter... but I am open to general design suggestions as well.

I've copied the entirety of my code here.

```
public class ConfigExample
{
    private HashSet<ConfigEntry> _entries;
    private Dictionary<string, Type> _entryTypes; 

    public ConfigExample()
    {
        _entries = new HashSet<ConfigEntry>();
    }

    public dynamic this[string propName]
    {
        get
        {
            var e = _entries.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PropertyName == propName);
            var t = _entryTypes[propName];
            var cast = e as ConfigEntry<t>;
            if (cast != null)
                return cast.Value;
        }
        set
        {

        }
    }

    public dynamic Get(string propName)
    {
        var e = _entries.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PropertyName == propName);
        if (e == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Property name does not exist.");

        var castBool = e as ConfigEntry<bool>;
        if (castBool != null)
            return castBool.Value;

        var castInt = e as ConfigEntry<int>;
        if (castInt != null)
            return castInt.Value;

        var castString = e as ConfigEntry<string>;
        if (castString != null)
            return castString.Value;

        throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not cast value");
    }

    public T Get<T>(string propName)
    {
        var e = _entries.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PropertyName == propName);
        if (e == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Property name does not exist.");

        var cast = e as ConfigEntry<T>;
        if (cast == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Property is not of given type");

        return cast.Value;
    }

    public void Set<T>(string propName, T val)
    {
        var e = _entries.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PropertyName == propName);
        if (e == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Property does not exist.");

        var cast = e as ConfigEntry<T>;
        if (cast == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Property is not of given type.");

        cast.Value = val;
    }
}

internal abstract class ConfigEntry
{
    protected ConfigEntry(string propName)
    {
        PropertyName = propName;
    }

    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
}

internal class ConfigEntry<T> : ConfigEntry
{
    public ConfigEntry(string propName, T val) : base(propName)
    {
        Value = val;
    }

    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you need to use dynamic, if you have already a generic approach using Get<T>()

Comment: @JohnField 1. That is not an option on an indexer. 2. I don't think my Get<T>() method is very good.

Comment: @Michael Why not box your `Get` and your indexer into `object` instead of using `dynamic`.

Comment: I believe the Get<T>() is the way to go. For square bracket overloading the only option would be making your class generic. if I were you I would definitely get rid of square indexer and the method public dynamic Get (or  box into an object instead)

Comment: I will likely use the Get<T> method. I misspoke in my earlier comment, I meant that I don't like my dynamic Get() method. However, this leaves the underlying question unanswered: Can I store a Type and use it as a Type Parameter?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Type parameters are meant to be checked at compile time, but if you retrieve a type from a dictionary, how do you know what type is it at compile time?

Comment: Right... compile time check. This is a feature I've tried to abuse before, I realize now. Question answered, problem solved.